# paragraph clustering when line breaks

Tags: html, css

How can I make my paragraph not clustering all the text up when there's a line break?

I'd like to still have a line break. But it should be in a more orderly fashion.

I attached an image to show.

[image]

```
<div class='se'>
    <p>Aerospace/Defense - Major Diversified</p>
    <p>Aerospace/Defense Products & Services</p>
    <p>Cement</p>
    <p>Diversified Machinery</p>
</div>

.sector3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    line-height: 40%;
}
```

Comment: Gluttering? Clustering? What does that mean?

Comment: I am not a css expert, but isn't the line-height attribute a problem at 40%?

Comment: @j08691 well for a lack of better word... A mess?

Comment: You should use margin to edit p space. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `line-height: 40%;` that change the height of each line.

To change the space between `p` use `margin:5px 0;` for the p of your parent.

If you want to know more about `line-height` read [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/).

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/htv62wL1/2/).

```css
.one {
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    line-height: 40%;
}
.two {
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.two p {
    margin:5px 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>
Yours:
</h2>
<div class="one">
    <p>Aerospace/Defense - Major Diversified</p>
    <p>Aerospace/Defense Products Services</p>
    <p>Cement</p>
    <p>Diversified Machinery</p>
</div>
<h2>
Without 'line-height: 40%':
</h2>
<div class="two">
    <p>Aerospace/Defense - Major Diversified</p>
    <p>Aerospace/Defense Products Services</p>
    <p>Cement</p>
    <p>Diversified Machinery</p>
</div>
```

Comment: if I remove it I'll get a wide spacing between the paragraphs. Is there a way to remove it and adjust the space?

Comment: Edited with new demo

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use a line height in percent of the current font size**. Have you defined a font-size of the parent of this element 'sector3' ?